# Django-Parsley Not Displaying Errors

Tags: python, django, parsley.js

I just installed django-parsley to give it a try for my forms. For testing, I'm trying to set it up on a simple front-end blog posting form: https://dpaste.de/Hh57

I'm able to view source on the page and see that the data-parsley attributes are added to each input field of my form. But, nothing happens. I noticed that the parsley.js file was not showing in the `<head>` when I viewed source so I copied `parsley.js` over to my static files directory and manually added a link to it and still not getting anything happening when I submit the blank form.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added `{{ form.media }}` to your template?

Comment: I didn't know I needed to add that anywhere? Sorry, I'm pretty new to django. That said, I added it to my template where I've got my form and it didn't add anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the fix to my problem.

In the django-parsley readme on github: https://github.com/agiliq/django-parsley

It instructs to put your form inside of:

```
<form parsley-validate>
    {{ form.as_p }}
</form>
```

This is what I was trying with no luck. I ended up finding another article which showed they were using:

```
<form data-parsley-validate>
```

Which seems to work.